# Shiny: How to return variables from observe()

Tags: r, shiny

The following code I have works as I intend for the first part of my application:

## ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyAce)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

tags$head(
tags$link(rel="stylesheet", type="text/css", href="styles.css")
    ),


headerPanel(
list(HTML('<img src="photo.jpg" HEIGHT="70" WIDTH="60" BORDER="0"/><font face="Myriad Pro""  
color="#005691"><br>APP</font>')),

),

sidebarPanel(

selectInput("simtype", "Select Simulation Type", c(SingleSubject="SS", FromFile="FF" ),   
selected="FF", multiple=FALSE),

conditionalPanel(condition="input.simtype=='FF' ",

  fileInput('file1', 'Upload File Here',
            accept=c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', '.csv')),


  tags$hr(),

  checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),

  radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
               c(Comma=',',
                 Semicolon=';',
                 Tab='\t'),
               'Comma'),

  uiOutput('varselect1')

),

conditionalPanel(condition="input.simtype== 'SS' ",

                helpText(HTML("
                              <ul>
                              <li>Insert SUVmax values in black window below</li>
                              <li>Each row corresponds to a timepoint</li>
                              <li>Enter each lesion's SUVmax value separated by a space</li>
                              </ul>")),


       aceEditor("text", "",
       mode="r", theme="twilight", height="40px",fontSize = 10 ),

                uiOutput('varselect2')

                )
),


mainPanel(




tabsetPanel(

tabPanel(title='FILE', value="filetab", loadingPanel, tableOutput("filetable")),
tabPanel(title='PLOT', value="plottab", loadingPanel, plotOutput("histogram")),
tabPanel(title="SUMMARY", value="summarytab",loadingPanel,dataTableOutput("summarytable")),
id="tabs"


        ) 
      )
))
```

## server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyAce)

shinyServer(


function(input, output, session) {


 observe({   

   if (input$simtype=="FF"){  

    csvfile <- reactive({
    csvfile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(csvfile)){return(NULL)}
    read.csv(csvfile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep,   quote=input$quote)
  })

  output$varselect1 <- renderUI({
      if(is.null(input$file1$datapath)){return()} 

      output$filetable <- renderTable({
    #isolate(input$tabs)
      csvfile()
    })


list(
  checkboxGroupInput("var", "Variables", choices = names(csvfile()), select = names(csvfile())),
  numericInput("s0", "Noise Distribution variance:", NULL),
  numericInput("n.it",'Number of Simulations: ', 1000),
  actionButton("goButton",'Create Plot and Summary Statistics'))

 }) # end renderUI()

 }   # end if

}) # end observe  

observe({  
  if (input$simtype=="SS"){     # Single-Subject Input

   output$varselect2<- renderUI({

     get.text <- reactive({
       input$text
     })  

     if(input$text == ""){return()}

     output$filetable <- renderTable({
       X<- read.table(text=get.text())
       j=1:ncol(X)
       i=1:nrow(X)
       colnames(X) <- paste("Lesion", j, sep=" ")  
       rownames(X) <- paste("Timepoint", i, sep=" ")
       X  
     })


    list(
     #
       # aceEditor("text", "Enter SUV vals. here",     
            # mode="r", theme="twilight", height="40px",fontSize = 10 ),


   numericInput("s0", "Noise Distribution variance:", NULL),
   numericInput("n.it",'Number of Simulations: ', 1000),
   actionButton("goButton",'Create Plot and Summary Statistics'))


   }) #end renderUI()
 } #end if       


 }) #end observe 

})
```

Namely, I am selecting a panel conditional on a selectInput, and then changing the UI based on that selection.   The problem is, this only seems to work when my conditional logic is wrapped in calls to observe() as above, so that I can render the correct output table on the file tab depending on which output type is chosen via selectInput.

Now, I want to use the output from the two cases, i.e., I want to access csvfile() and X() in a later function call in server.R, which implies that I need to make them accessible outside the observe() calls.  Not sure how to do this.  Can anyone point me in the right direction or suggest an alternative? I realize this may just be a flow control issue, but for whatever reason, I'm not seeing it.

Thanks.

Comment: In the one shiny app I have made I ended up putting a lot of conditionals the tested if the inputs were empty because even just in the course of loading the page with "." for all the inputs the time between when the first input rendered and the last one did was enough to cause errors on the server side if I didn't. It seemed needlessly complicated but it did work.

Comment: Don't use a dot in input names, here use for instance `n_it` instead of `n.it`.

Comment: Could that be causing an issue, Stéphane?

Answer (score 1):

observe() doesn't return a value

reactive() does

Typically you can do something like

```
return_a_value <- reactive({... })

observe({
   ...
  something <- return_a_value()
  ....
})
```

Comment: You're missing the point of my question.  I realize observe() is the WRONG thing to use.  But I want to be able to call IF statements on the inputs.  I.e. I want to be able to say  `if (input$myinput == something) { run code}` but I can't write that statement unless I'm in a reactive environment, right?

Answer (score 0):

try with `isolate`

```
 observe({   

   test  <- isolate(input$simtype)

   if (test=="FF"){  

    csvfile <- reactive({
    csvfile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(csvfile)){return(NULL)}
    read.csv(csvfile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep,   quote=input$quote)
  })
```